# Codeigniter: Controller too big, how to separate it into smaller chunks?

Tags: php, codeigniter, controllers

The problem I am having is that my_controller.php has over 1000 lines of code. And while I have no problem navigating trough it I would like to place parts of that controller in some other files.

In more detail:

I have a controller that contains a CRUD functions (not the model functions, controller functions, meaning that there are no db queries there) for a specific object (and its children)

Now, for each of the CRUD I have a function that serves as the controller (the one that is accessed via url, in case of the Create part, it will prepare a form), a function that manages the data from the form (gets the POST and sends it to validation, and if it is ok send the data for further preparation) and validation (validates the data via the callbacks) and preparation (mostly for calling the model method and sending it a prepared array of data ).

Since the CRUD for all of the objects in this controller work with mostly same data, they share many functions.

So I would like to create specific .php that store the functions for validation, callback functions, for preparation etc.

What is the best way to do this?

What is the common procedure or good practice when creating CRUD controllers?

I hope that I was clear enough, my knowledge of both the langauge and php programming is rather limited.

Comment: Simple answer: make one new controller per child object.  If you want more specific help, need to see some code.

Comment: Put all you validation functions in a library file, or a helper file.

Comment: Other alternative is using Hooks: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html

Answer (score 1):

You have a "fat" controller. One option is to see what can be easily pushed to the model, so that you have a "thin controller fat model". One way to think about models is that its your database table AND the business rules for how that data is used. So things like validation and data prep can happen in the model. Then the controller just hands off and collects objects and arrays. And models can directly call other models.

If you dont like that approach, or you need something more portable, then use libraries. The other thing to look at is if there are short bits (technical term) that you need in different places -- look at putting those in a site config file.

Comment: I tend to use models only for database access. I build my model so that it has no knowledge of the view part.

Comment: I tend to use models only for database access. I build my model so that it has no knowledge of the view part. I have been considering putting each of my controller functions (the one called in the url) in the separate .php and in a subfolder, this how ever created some problems where I have to define routes etc... will see.

Comment: just to clarify - i'm Not saying the model needs to know about the view. imho the controller determines what model to call, and what to send to the view. where you want to put the 'in between' methods like data validation is up to you.